# How to skip text and only use integers in a when getting max value of cells in DGV? Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, integer

I am using a `DataGridView` in my program I want to get the maximum value in a column of cells in a `DataGridView`.

My problem is that some cells also contain words and my code gives me a n error that the word cant be converted to type integer.

I know I need to get it to skip these cells but don't know how to accomplish this yet.

```
  Private Sub Timer11_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer11.Tick
    Dim MaxVal As Double = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(1).Value > MaxVal Then MaxVal = row.Cells(1).Value 'Maximum value of first column
    Next
    PEAK_IM3TextBox.Text = MaxVal.ToString()
    Timer13.Start()
    Timer11.Stop()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Tryparse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
  Private Sub Timer11_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer11.Tick
    Dim MaxVal As Double = -199
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        'Check if value in cell is double

        Dim ParseValue As Integer = 0
        If Double.TryParse(row.Cells(1).Value, ParseValue) Then

            If ParseValue > MaxVal Then
                MaxVal = ParseValue
            End If

        End If
    Next
    PEAK_IM3TextBox.Text = MaxVal.ToString()
    Timer13.Start()
    Timer11.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good direction for me to look this method allows for the cell with the text to be counted as an integer but this then only allows me to get this value of PraseValue as I am working in the -0 range and when I uses to the - I get -132 but the number I am looking for is -111.41

Comment: Glad i could be of some assistance!